# apache php find original link of permalink

Tags: php, apache

I am having a wordpress site on my local server on LAMP. and had a virtual host `himalaya.com`

I have a link `himalaya.com/ganga` I want to know how this link searches for the required file from the wordpress directory (himalaya.com).

In the respose headers i found some link himalaya.com/?p=763 and when i opened it, it shows the same link as `himalaya.com`

Then i tried to search for the file `?p=763`, but there is no such file in the directory `himalaya.com`. So I am confused how apache is getting the file.

Comment: `?p=763` is the same as `index.php?p=763` (or any other default file you have set in your config file - if you don't know, it's most likely `index.php`). Wordpress has an inbuilt router in `index.php` that opens the correct PHP files. Google "wordpress rewrite".

Comment: thankyou i will find out about the rewrtie. But how could you say that `index.php?p=763` is same as `?p=763`. Also what does `index.php?p=763` means

Comment: Anything after `?` is a [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) (also known as GET params). These are sent onto the site being requested (you can access these in PHP by using `$_GET`). Just like `domain.com/` is the same as `domain.com/index.php`, then `domain.com/?foo=bar` will be the same as `domain.com/index.php?foo=bar`.

Comment: ok thank you.I am using wordpress. Which is the php file in general uses the $_GET. Because i saw index.php, it contains nothing, instead its written that `Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.`

Comment: It may be any PHP file on your system - it may be several even.

Comment: is there any way to find out any one of them.